# How to improve the speed of a lot of small files' read and write?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, hbase, database, nosql

My Job is to Improve the speed of reading a lot of small file (1KB) from disk to write into our database.
The database is open source to me, and I can change all the code from the client to the server.
The database architecture is that , it is a simple master-slave distributed  HDFS based database like HBase. The small file from disk can be insert into our database and combined into bigger block automatically and then write into HDFS.(also the big file can be split to smaller block by database and then write into HDFS)

One way to change the client is to increase the thread number.
I don't have any other idea.Or you can provide some idea to do the performance analysis.

Comment: Finally we read the files from distributed machine to increase the speed

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to process such small files could be to convert these small files to a sequence file and store it into HDFS. Then use this file as a Map Reduce job input file to put the data into HBase or similar database.

Answer (score 0):

This uses aws as an example but it could be any storage/queue setup:

If the files were able to exist on a shared storage such as S3 you could add one queue entry for each file and then just start throwing servers at the queue to add the files to the db. At that point the bottleneck becomes the db instead of the client.